# Send Facebook Notification from Website PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I have integrated Facebook like and share button on PHP website. I was trying to send notification from website to Facebook app users.

Tried the stuff available on internet and [facebook developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications) but not able to get any clear idea.

Can anyone guide me or provide me a clear source?

This is my first time using Facebook PHP SDK (I don't have much knowledge on Facebook PHP SDK).

Thank you.

Comment: Try this link http://hayageek.com/login-with-facebook-twitter-google-php/

Comment: That is not available for external websites. Your app needs a canvas implementation for this to work.